# Page not found at /posts even though View, template and Url config in defined

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building a simple blog app and trying to use slugs in the URL. I have defined the URL as well as the view and the template, however when I try to access the URL /blog/posts, it throws a 404 that too from an entirely different view. All other URLs work, just having an issue with above mentioned one.

url.py

```
 urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.IndexView.as_view(),name='index'),
    path('create/',views.PostCreateView.as_view(),name='blog-create'),
    path('posts/',views.UserPosts.as_view(),name='user-posts'),
    path('<slug:slug>',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='blog-detail'),
    path('list/',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='blog-list'),
    path('<slug:slug>/comment/',views.create_comment,name='comment'),
]
```

Associated Views in order

```
class PostDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
    slug_field = 'slug'

class UserPosts(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'blog/user_post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        posts = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = posts.objects.all(user= self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

the 404 error

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/posts
Raised by:  blog.views.PostDetailView
No post found found matching the query
```

template directory tree

```
blog/
   templates/
            blog/
                user_post_list.html
```

Also earlier I had a problem with path('/list') as well however it got solved when I removed the '/' from the slug URL, I don't know why it worked, can anyone explain?